# Twilio VoIP Call Delegate handling in swift

Tags: swift, voip, twilio-click-to-call

Some can explain which delegate method to handle VoIP calling received call and not answer and disconnected call callback. How to know these elements occur in Twilio and have some explanation over incoming call when app is not running state.

Answer (score 0):

You use [TVOCallDelegate](https://twilio.github.io/twilio-voice-ios/docs/latest/Protocols/TVOCallDelegate.html) for the twilio calls handling. And [TVONotificaitonDelegate](https://twilio.github.io/twilio-voice-ios/docs/latest/Classes/TVOCallInvite.html) for the calls invite notifications handling.

```
func callInviteReceived(callInvite: CallInvite)
```

This is called when a call is incoming, you can do any logic e.g map names to phone number etc inside this, but then you to call the reportNewIncomingCall method for apple to know that a call is incoming and we have done specific calculations on that, but keep in mind, the time to do calculations is very little, and cannot exceed a certain limit, otherwise apple will generate a crash.

```
func callDidConnect(call: Call)
```

This is called when the call is picked from receiver end or the twilio's text to speech "twilio.say()" function is called. Use this to start call timer etc.

```
func callDidDisconnect(call: Call, error: Error?)
```

This is called when the call is disconnected, either receiver disconnects or no answer etc, you can check in the error object to see what was the cause of disconnect.

Also there are also options available on twilio cloud based codes to handle these scenarios if more advance and faster solutions are required.